# SDWebImage not downloading the image swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, image, sdwebimage

Here, I am trying to show the image by using SDWebImage. It is only showing placeholder. Here is the code:

```
cell.docImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "http://suggestnepal.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/2011-12-13-1323775332.jpg")!, placeholderImage:"noImage")
```

I have used a sample image at present. It is opening in the browser but not showing the imageView. Even also, I have tried with a placeholder image:

http://via.placeholder.com/1200x1600

Please revert !!

Comment: Was it working before? What about using the `sd_setImage()` version with the closure that could give you the error in case of fail? App Transport Security ?

Comment: It is only working when, I am fetching the image url from my app's server but not from any other images like the one is mentioned and the placeholder image.

Comment: Hey.. It worked.. I was missing App Transport Security check. Thanks alot :)